# Best Cache mode value for lookup component in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I Use `SSIS` for convert data from old database to new database. source database have about 900 tables and destination database have about 300 tables. some of these tables have huge data and some of these have static data. I use several (about 100) `Lookup` component in my packages and all these component adjusting with full cache mode. I don't know what time must be use full cache, partial cache or no cache mode. I trust that lookup cache mode relate with row count of lookup table, but don't know what time I must set lookup cache mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably depends on your processing requirements. If you are simply converting from an old system to a new system, I suggest using a No Cache option. Using a full cache might cripple your package as the package will need to buffer all the rows before it can start processing. If this is a production environment, it could severely effect the overall system.

I think, on the smaller tables, using the full cache mode would not hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to choose partial cache because you have large data in your package. If you use full cache, it needs lots of memory so performance decreases